# "Detected prob_lem with app native libraries" message on certain phones

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

[image: Message]

Everytime I run the app, I get this error message. There is nothing in the app, it is just a basic Navigation drawer template you get in the studio. The message only appears on certain devices (I ran it on a Zenfone 2 with Lineage OS(7.1.1)). My SDK version is 25 and I'm running android studio 2.3.1.

The message says: 
Detected problems with app native libraries (please consult log for details):

libavcodec.so: text relocations

libswresample.so: text relocations

```
Log:

04-08 21:53:06.321 6798-6798/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-08 21:53:06.482 6798-6798/com.platformpetal.platformpetal W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.platformpetal.platformpetal-1/lib/x86
04-08 21:53:06.494 6798-6798/com.platformpetal.platformpetal I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
04-08 21:53:06.664 6798-6831/com.platformpetal.platformpetal I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-08 21:53:06.664 6798-6831/com.platformpetal.platformpetal D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
04-08 21:53:06.665 6798-6831/com.platformpetal.platformpetal W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
04-08 21:53:06.665 6798-6831/com.platformpetal.platformpetal D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
04-08 21:53:08.704 6798-6798/com.platformpetal.platformpetal W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-08 21:53:09.158 6798-6798/com.platformpetal.platformpetal W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
04-08 21:53:09.598 6798-6798/com.platformpetal.platformpetal E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.platformpetal.platformpetal.SplashScreen has leaked window DecorView@aaf4c69[] that was originally added here
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:418)
                                                                              at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:331)
                                                                              at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
                                                                              at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:322)
                                                                              at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:1112)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6718)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2628)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776
```

)

Here the error message is for the activity being terminated before the message closes. There is nothing I can find which can cause the issue.

P.S. Stack Overflow doesn't allow word problem in question, so I wrote prob_lem
P.P.S. I'm relatively new to android, so don't be harsh :)

Comment: did you find the solution for this problem?

Comment: No. I didn't. It still persists

Comment: any one find-out any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is documented in https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk => you need to bundle those .so files with your application, apparently.